# Task.WaitSubset / Task.WaitN?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

There're `Task.WaitAll` method which waits for all tasks and `Task.WaitAny` method which waits for one task. How to wait for any N tasks?

Use case: search result pages are downloaded, each result needs a separate task to download and process it. If I use `WaitAll` to wait for the results of the subtasks before getting next search result page, I will not use all available resources (one long task will delay the rest). Not waiting at all can cause thousands of tasks to be queued which isn't the best idea either.

So, how to wait for a subset of tasks to be completed? Or, alternatively, how to wait for the task scheduler queue to have only N tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an excellent problem for TPL Dataflow, which will allow you to control parallelism and buffering to process at maximum speed.

Here's some (untested) code to show you what I mean:

```
static void Process()
{
    var searchReader =
        new TransformManyBlock<SearchResult, SearchResult>(async uri =>
    {
        // return a list of search results at uri.

        return new[]
        {
            new SearchResult
            {
                IsResult = true,
                Uri = "http://foo.com"
            },
            new SearchResult
            {
                // return the next search result page here.
                IsResult = false,
                Uri = "http://google.com/next"
            }
        };
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 8, // restrict buffer size.
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 // control parallelism.
    });

    // link "next" pages back to the searchReader.
    searchReader.LinkTo(searchReader, x => !x.IsResult);

    var resultActor = new ActionBlock<SearchResult>(async uri =>
    {
        // do something with the search result.
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 64,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16
    });

    // link search results into resultActor.
    searchReader.LinkTo(resultActor, x => x.IsResult);

    // put in the first piece of input.
    searchReader.Post(new SearchResult { Uri = "http://google/first" });
}

struct SearchResult
{
    public bool IsResult { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should independently limit the number of parallel download tasks and the number of concurrent result processing tasks. I would do it using two [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects, like below. This version doesn't use the synchronous `SemaphoreSlim.Wait` (thanks @svick for making the point). It was only slightly tested, the exception handling can be improved; substitute your own `DownloadNextPageAsync` and `ProcessResults`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console_21666797
{
    partial class Program
    {
        // the actual download method
        // async Task<string> DownloadNextPageAsync(string url) { ... }

        // the actual process methods
        // void ProcessResults(string data) { ... }

        // download and process all pages
        async Task DownloadAndProcessAllAsync(
            string startUrl, int maxDownloads, int maxProcesses)
        {
            // max parallel downloads
            var downloadSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDownloads);
            // max parallel processing tasks
            var processSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxProcesses);

            var tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
            var complete = false;
            var protect = new Object(); // protect tasks

            var page = 0;

            // do the page
            Func<string, Task> doPageAsync = async (url) =>
            {
                bool downloadSemaphoreAcquired = true;
                try
                {
                    // download the page
                    var data = await DownloadNextPageAsync(
                        url).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                    {
                        Volatile.Write(ref complete, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // enable the next download to happen
                        downloadSemaphore.Release();
                        downloadSemaphoreAcquired = false;

                        // process this download 
                        await processSemaphore.WaitAsync();
                        try
                        {
                            await Task.Run(() => ProcessResults(data));
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            processSemaphore.Release();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Volatile.Write(ref complete, true);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (downloadSemaphoreAcquired)
                        downloadSemaphore.Release();
                }
            };

            // do the page and save the task
            Func<string, Task> queuePageAsync = async (url) =>
            {
                var task = doPageAsync(url);

                lock (protect)
                    tasks.Add(task);

                await task;

                lock (protect)
                    tasks.Remove(task);
            }; 

            // process pages in a loop until complete is true 
            while (!Volatile.Read(ref complete))
            {
                page++;

                // acquire download semaphore synchrnously
                await downloadSemaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // do the page 
                var task = queuePageAsync(startUrl + "?page=" + page);
            }

            // await completion of the pending tasks
            Task[] pendingTasks;
            lock (protect)
                pendingTasks = tasks.ToArray();
            await Task.WhenAll(pendingTasks);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().DownloadAndProcessAllAsync("http://google.com", 10, 5).Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. There might be some edge cases, but all in all it should ensure a minimum of completions.

```
public static async Task WhenN(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, int n, CancellationTokenSource cts = null)
{
    var pending = new HashSet<Task>(tasks);

    if (n > pending.Count)
    {
        n = pending.Count;

        // or throw
    }

    var completed = 0;

    while (completed != n)
    {
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(pending);

        pending.Remove(completedTask);

        completed++;
    }

    if (cts != null)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var completed = 0;
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(temp * 100, cts.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Completed task {0}", i);
            completed++;
        }, cts.Token));
    }

    Extensions.WhenN(tasks, 30, cts).Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(completed);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. You start all the `Task`s at the same time, so this doesn't do any throttling. In the end, your code is pretty much just a complicated way to implement `Task.WhenAll()`.

Comment: @svick you are right, I left out the throttling part. I only implemented the "how to wait for any tasks?" and "So, how to wait for a subset of tasks to be completed?" part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Task[] runningTasks = MyTasksFactory.StartTasks();

while(runningTasks.Any())
{
 int finished = Task.WaitAny(runningTasks);

 Task.Factory.StareNew(()=> {Consume(runningTasks[Finished].Result);}) 

 runningTasks.RemoveAt(finished);

}
```